# text color of disabled uibarbuttonitem is always the color of the normal state

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

i wrote in my code

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]  setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor lightGrayColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f]} forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]  setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but the text color is always blue despite the baritem being disabled.

I'm programming in xcode 5 and ios7

Comment: Where do you have that code? It works of me if I put it in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method in the app delegate. If I put it in viewDidLoad of a controller it does turn gray if I disable the button later, but it won't take the initial color, if I make it red when enabled for instance.

Comment: i have it in  application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: ... hmm weird

Comment: I am setting several appearance proxies for many types of views (basically, theming my whole app). Somehow, setting the normal and disabled state of UIBarButtonItem does not work if there is already a custom `tintColor` in the hierarchy. I removed all calls to `UIBarButtonItem,appearance()...`, and left it to the (custom) global tint color to decide. Now the normal state appears in my custom control tint color, and the disabled in gray.

Answer (score 4):

for me following `code` works.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem * btnTemp = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(btnDone_Click:)];
    [btnTemp setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor lightGrayColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [btnTemp setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f]} forState:UIControlStateDisabled];


    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:btnTemp];

}

- (void)btnDone_Click : (id)sender {

    UIBarButtonItem * button = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
    [button setEnabled:FALSE];
    [self performSelector:@selector(enableButton:) withObject:sender afterDelay:2.0f];


}

- (void)enableButton : (id)sender {
    UIBarButtonItem * button = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
    [button setEnabled:TRUE];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that it's because I set the navigationBar to unhidden after I called self.navigationItem.rightBarItem.enable. Putting the latter after the former fixes the problem

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and solved it by declaring the normal-button-state without any colorinformation.

Swift example:

```
    myBtn.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "xxx", size: 20.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    myBtn.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "xxx", size: 20.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.darkGrayColor()], forState: UIControlState.Disabled)
```

just becomes

```
    myBtn.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "xxx", size: 20.0)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I'm not sure but I think it was because I declared also a `tintColor` in XCode.